# Agregar varias consultas en un Gridview ASP y SQL

Tags: c#, sql, select, asp, gridview

tengo una tabla con una lista enorme de materiales, necesito seleccionar varios materiales para posteriormente generar un PDF con dichos materiales, estoy trabado en esa parte puesto que no se como ir agregando varios materiales sin que se borre el primero, es decir, el usuario hará aprox 5-10 SELECT pero ahora mismo solo puedo mostrar 1 en el gridview

Comment: César, necesitamos más detalles. Puedes echar un vistazo al [centro de ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help) para saber [cómo elaborar una buena pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Necesitaremos código de lo que has intentado, una idea del resultado esperado, etc